# Shiny datepicker with custom CSS

Tags: css, r, shiny

I'm trying to use Material-Kit CSS in shiny and for the most part it works fine but when using the `dateInput` control, the dropdown does not appear. I even tried putting in the sample HTML code from Material-Kit docs directly and the dropdown doesn't appear either:

```
HTML('<div class="form-group label-static">
      <label class="control-label">Datepicker</label>
        <input type="text" class="datepicker form-control" value="03/12/2016" />
    </div>')
```

Comment: Do you use shinymaterial ?

Comment: I am using the bootstrap 3 version of: http://demos.creative-tim.com/material-kit/index.html

Comment: May be you could provide a reproductible code sample (with a minimal shiny code and the convenient exerpt from CSS or any other code needed) .. It is unlikely that someone will help you otherwise, because your case is very specific and I don't think people will spend time downloading the kit and learning how to use it just for your sake